# What are possible values we can expect as a breakdown of insights API

Tags: facebook-marketing-api, facebook-insights

Does Facebook marketing API document talks about possible values we can expect for the breakdown in insights call?

Example for the below API call,

https://graph.facebook.com/v2.12/(account_id)/insights?access_token=(access_token)&level=campaign&breakdowns=age&fields=campaign_id,campaign_name,objective,spend&date_preset=this_month

the response comes with the age-wise breakdown for each campaign, here age comes with any of the possible values from 
 [13-17, 18-24, 25-34, 35-44, 45-54, 55-64, 65+]

like this what are the possible values we can expect from all other breakdowns such as impression_device, gender, device_platform, platform_position, publisher_platform